# How to invoke authentication of user to determine id service should be performed with a soap web service call with servicestack?

Tags: authentication, soap, servicestack

I am new to servicestack. I need to authenticate the soap request with userid and password implementing servicestack.

I have created a custom CredentialsAuthProvider which override this method:

```
public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService,
string userName, string password)
```

and added

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
               new IAuthProvider[] {
                    new SFCredentialsAuthProvider(),
               } 
to config in AppHost.
```

My issue is how am I supposed to authenticate the user from the soap web service call?

The examples show something like:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUrl);

var authResponse = client.Post(new Authenticate {
    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name, //= credentials
    UserName = "test@gmail.com",
    Password = "p@55w0rd",
    RememberMe = true,
});
```

But what should this BaseUrl be, given that I will only perform the service if the request is authenticated?

I am lost on how to invoke authentication while performing the soap service on servicestack. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a long while since I solved this issue with BasicAuthProvider. sample code below:

```
public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService,
        string userName, string password)
    {
        var httpReq = authService.Request;
        var basicAuth = httpReq.GetBasicAuthUserAndPassword();
        if (basicAuth == null)
            throw HttpError.Unauthorized(ErrorMessages.InvalidBasicAuthCredentials.Localize(authService.Request));

        var userid = basicAuth.Value.Key;
        var pwd = basicAuth.Value.Value;
```

//authenticate with the userid and password

}

Comment: Just want to post it here in case it will help someone else new to servicestack for auth

Answer (score 0):

The `BaseUrl` should be the base URL where your ServiceStack Services are hosted at, e.g. for your local IIS Express dev server it typically takes the format of `http://localhost:{PortNumber}` which is loaded when you hit `F5` to run your App.

Not sure what your question has to do with SOAP since you're using the `JsonServiceClient` which is calling a JSON HTTP API. For SOAP you'd generally add a **WCF Service Reference** at the ServiceStack `/wsdl` endpoint to generate a client proxy from the WSDL definition, which you'd use to access your Services.

But when you don't need to use SOAP [you should avoid it](https://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack) and just use the `JsonServiceClient` as shown in your example.